# To vectorize a function operating across dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

Some stylized data to start with:

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame(data = [(1, 'AA', 'ServiceA'), (2, 'BB', 'ServiceB'), (3, 'CC', 'ServiceA'), (4, 'DD', 'ServiceD')], 
                      columns=['Rev', 'Pnum', 'Service'])
   Rev  Pnum    Service
0   1   AA      ServiceA
1   2   BB      ServiceB
2   3   CC      ServiceA
3   4   DD      ServiceD
```

To apportion value of services we have:

```
pnumlist = ['AA', 'CC']
servicelist = ['ServiceA', 'ServiceB', 'ServiceC', 'ServiceD']
```

I'm trying to write a Pythonic function that'd take above df and return another df based on:

```
testdf['Charge'] = testdf['Rev'] if testdf['Pnum'] in pnumlist else 0 #doesn't work, throws truth value ambiguous error
```

The returned df should also have columns for counts of the various services in each line of the testdf, so it should look like:

```
outputdf = pd.DataFrame(data = [(1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0, 0), (3, 1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1)],
                       columns = ['Charge', 'Acount', 'Bcount', 'Ccount', 'Dcount'])
```

At the moment I have a rowhandler func that handles each row of testdf and then I call apply with this df passing the rowhandlder func:

```
def rowhandler(testdfrow: tuple) -> tuple:
    testdfrow['Charge'] = testdfrow['Rev'] if testdfrow['Pnum'] in pnumlist else 0
    for service in servicelist:
        testdfrow['{}count'.format(service)] = 1 if service in testdfrow['Service'] else 0
    return testdfrow

newcolslist = ['Charge']
newcolsdict = {col: 0 for col in newcolslist}
testdf = testdf.assign(**newcolsdict) #pre-allocating memory speeds up program
testdf = testdf.apply(rowhandler, axis = 1)
```

The rowhandler func has several other columns in real situation and the data size is also large. So I'm looking for ways to speed it up and I think it can be done by vectorizing the rowhandler func. Any suggestions appreciated, thanks

Comment: Do you actually need a new dataframe, or will adding to the current one work?

Comment: Good question, in this case I don't but I'd actually asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245895/to-vectorize-a-function-operating-across-dataframe-columns?noredirect=1#comment99110362_56245895) earlier hinting towards a new df but at that time I'd not developed my thinking or code appropriately. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just edit your dataframe in place using column based operations. For example:

```
testdf["Charge"] = testdf["Rev"].where(testdf["Pnum"].isin(pnumlist), 0)

for service in servicelist:
    testdf["{}_count".format(service)] = testdf["Service"].str.contains(service).astype(int)
```

Here's some performance comparisons:

```
import timeit

testdf = pd.concat([testdf for i in range(10000)], ignore_index=True)

def fix_df():
    global testdf
    testdf["Charge"] = testdf["Rev"].where(testdf.Pnum.isin(pnumlist), 0)

    for service in servicelist:
        testdf["{}count".format(service)] = (
            testdf["Service"].str.contains(service).astype(int)
        )
    return testdf


def fix_df_orig():
    global testdf

    def rowhandler(testdfrow: tuple) -> tuple:
        testdfrow["Charge"] = testdfrow["Rev"] if testdfrow["Pnum"] in pnumlist else 0
        for service in servicelist:
            testdfrow["{}count".format(service)] = (
                1 if service in testdfrow["Service"] else 0
            )
        return testdfrow

    newcolslist = ["Charge"]
    newcolsdict = {col: 0 for col in newcolslist}
    testdf = testdf.assign(**newcolsdict)  # pre-allocating memory speeds up program
    testdf = testdf.apply(rowhandler, axis=1)

In [1]: timeit.timeit(fix_df, number=1)
Out[1]: 0.06966943305451423

In [2]: timeit.timeit(fix_df_orig, number=1)
Out[2]: 109.82892861706205
```

Seems like quite the improvement.

edit:
I updated my answer with a slightly more performant answer

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need `get_dummies` with `concat`  ?

```
s1=testdf[['Rev']].where(testdf.Pnum.isin(pnumlist),0)
s2=testdf['Service'].where(testdf['Service'].isin(servicelist)).str.get_dummies()
df=pd.concat([s1,s2.reindex(columns=servicelist,fill_value=0)],1)
df
Out[563]: 
   Rev  ServiceA  ServiceB  ServiceC  ServiceD
0    1         1         0         0         0
1    0         0         1         0         0
2    3         1         0         0         0
3    0         0         0         0         1
```